# "Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ''" error when trying to save in JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am currently trying to save all the commands for my discord bot inside a JSON file, but when I try to add more than one command, the app crashes and throws out the error "JSONError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '' in projects\discordbot\commands.json"

I have already tried to print out the JSON.
After the first command is added the commands.json file is this:

```
{
  "help": {
    "description": "Displays the help",
    "allowUser": true
  }
}
```

When I now load the next command, it gets to the point where it loads the JSON file, but then the app crashes.

My function for adding the command:

```
createCommand: (command, description, allowUser) => 
    {
        console.log("createCommand: " + command);
        let cmds = loadJson.sync(__dirname + "/commands.json");
        if(!cmds.hasOwnProperty(command)) cmds[command] = {
            "description": description,
            "allowUser": allowUser
        };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(cmds, undefined, 2));
        fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/commands.json", JSON.stringify(cmds, undefined, 2), (err) => {});
    },
```

And I load the commands here:

```
loadCommands: () => //Add your own commands here and handle them in the index.js file
    {
        const createCmd = module.exports.createCommand;
        createCmd("help", "Displays the help", true);
        createCmd("cleanup", "Cleans up the channel", false);
        /*createCmd("poke", "Pokes the bot", true);
        createCmd("admins", "Shows a list of staff", true);
        createCmd("developer", "Shows the developer", true);
        createCmd("userinfo", "Shows info about a given user", true);
        createCmd("warn", "Warns a given user", false);
        createCmd("unwarn", "Unwarns a given user", false);
        createCmd("feed", "Checks if a given user is feeding", true);
        createCmd("kick", "Kicks a given user", false);
        createCmd("ban", "Bans a given user", false);*/
    },
```

Comment: Can you show us your JSON with two or more commands? It sounds like it isn't being formatted correctly. (If it won't print two full commands, can you show us the file immediately after it fails?)

Comment: Are you sure it's failing on saving? The `fs.writeFile` and `JSON.stringify` are not parsing any JSON - But the error says it fails while parsing JSON input. That would indicate it's in fact probably failing on `loadJson.sync` method.

Comment: I can't because as I said, when I try to load more than one command, the app crashes. The function createCommand() gets executed, but the app crashes when it tries to load the JSON after a command has been added.

Comment: @LeonMrBonnie I understand that you can't view it through your app, as you said, it crashes. However, I assume a raw file is saved somewhere? Can you view this in a text editor when it fails to see exactly where it failed?

Comment: Yes, the raw file is stored locally, but is just completely empty after the app crashes. I do not know why, because I don't save that file anywhere else then that function

Comment: I now tested adding the commands one by one, and it works. The JSON is completely fine when I add them one by one, but when I try to add them one after another without restarting the app it throws out the error again, I don't understand this.

Answer (score 0):

No problem identified after replacing

```
loadJson.sync(__dirname + "/commands.json");
```

with

```
require(__dirname + "/commands.json");
```